# Preloading, lazy loaded pages Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

In Ionic 3 we had the option to preload pages by doing:

```
IonicModule.forRoot({
  preloadModules: true
});
```

But when I try to do that in Ionic 4, it gives me an error:

```
 Argument of type '{ preloadModules: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IonicConfig'.
```

Someones know how to do this in Ionic 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 4 under the hood uses Angular CLI, which supports Lazy Loading Modules. While creating Routes using forRoot(), forChild(). We can define the lazy loaded modules using loadChildren configuration.

```
const app_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: 'app/home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/login' }
];

RouterModule.forRoot(app_routes);
```

We are telling ionic/Angular CLI, when user access '/user' location path, we need to load the Home Module as lazyloaded, which will internally load the required components and services.

```
Ionic Docs: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/
```

Comment: Yep, but how can I preload those pages?

Comment: Inside HomeModule, we need to define RouteforChild() and preload the component.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that my pages take a lot of time to load because of the lazy loading, so I'd like to preload it, but, how could I do it in RouteforChild()?

Comment: Angular+Ionic 4 supports preloading stratergy. https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/preloading-modules-in-ionic-v4-1839c34384fb

Comment: thanks, it didnt made the app a lot more fast, but it was war I was looking for